# Newton: an object in motion remains in motion: was there anyone else who believed this?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, inertial-frames, history, inertia

From my own experience as a schoolkid, that was the law that I was not buying. I could see his understanding of the Lunar orbit making him think this but otherwise, what in human experience would lead someone to believe that an object in motion continues?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to me to be asked in good faith. Voting to close as needs details and clarity.

Comment: This is an empirical law. If an object in motion is subject to no net force, it stays in uniform linear motion. It's got nothing to do with "belief".

Comment: @JiminyCricket.: What? Good faith? My question is what could have led Newton or his predecessor to believe any object moved forever. Maybe I should ask in the history of science stack exchange.

Comment: @josephh: What empirical observation could Newton have experienced that would suggest this law? That is the central question.

Comment: This has been experimentally verified

Comment: @RyderRude:  The question is about Newton and I would like to know what experiment he performed.

Comment: If you've a question about the history of science, then please ask it on [hsm.se], you would need to show your research.

Comment: "_What empirical observation could Newton have experienced that would suggest this law?_" That is not what your question asked. Maybe you could argue that this is implicit in the question, but imo and others above, you should have been more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Galileo did the experiment to verify this. Newton borrowed his result. [image]

Take a double inclined plane, almost frictionless. Let a ball roll down from one end and see how much height it rises to on the other end. We find that, as we make the friction lower and lower, the ball rises to almost the same height that it was dropped from. Conclusion : If speed loss from fiction was absent, ball would've risen to exactly the same height on the other side.

Now imagine you increase the separation between the two inclines. Send the right incline infinitely far away, or better yet, just get rid of it. Now the ball, after it leaves the left incline, would forever keep moving with the same momentum, due to the absence of frictional losses.

Answer (score 2):

The three laws of motion have for a long time been called "Newton's" laws of motion, but Newton himself did not claim them as his own. He credited work of others before him, and included an acknowledgement of Galileo by name.  Thus, in the 'Principia' (here in its [1729 English translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tm0FAAAAQAAJ), at p.31) Newton wrote, after setting out the laws of motion as 'axioms', i.e. principles that he took to be well accepted, and thus did not propose to prove:-

> "Hitherto I have laid down such principles as have been receiv'd by
> mathematicians, and are confirm'd by abundance of experiments. By the
> two first Laws and the first two Corollaries, Galileo discover'd that
> the descent of bodies observ'd the duplicate ratio of the time, and
> that the motion of projectiles was in the curve of a Parabola;
> experience agreeing with both, unless so far as these motions are a
> little retarded by the resistance of the air."

(See also a [modified 'wikisource' translation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Principles_of_Natural_Philosophy_(1729)/Axioms,_or_Laws_of_Motion#Scholium).)

Others, well after Newton's lifetime, named the laws 'Newton's', probably in recognition that he compiled them together as a set, as well as making redefinitions of scope, so that as a set of laws of mechanics they were not together known or in use before Newton, and the effect of the whole was in this instance more than the effects of the parts.

[E Hecht, in The Physics Teacher 53, 80-83 (2015)](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.4905802) ("Origins of Newton's First Law") wrote

> "Anyone who has taught introductory physics should know
> that roughly a third of the students initially believe
> that any object at rest will remain at rest, whereas any
> moving body not propelled by applied forces will promptly
> come to rest. Likewise, about half of those uninitiated
> students believe that any object moving at a constant
> speed must be continually pushed if it is to maintain
> its motion."

Hecht's paper goes on to identify that Galileo recognized *a* law of inertia, although as he says, it did not express the generality or linearity of the later version, thus:

> [Galileo] argued in the *Dialogue Concerning the Two
> Chief World Systems* (1632), regarding moving bodies,
> “it is impossible that their motions should be straight… .”
> (p.19 in 1967 translation by Stillman Drake.)

Also, a principle of inertial motion in a horizontal plane:

> Galileo surmised that if the ... plane was horizontal and
> the process truly frictionless, the ball would travel
> forever. He asked his reader to
>
> “[i]magine any particle projected along a horizontal plane
> without friction; then we know, ... that this particle
> will move along this same plane with a motion which is
> uniform and perpetual provided the plane has no limits.”
> (citing Galileo Galilei, *Dialogues Concerning Two New
> Sciences*, translated by Henry Crew and Alfonso deSalvio
> (Dover Publications, New York, 1954), p.244).

(Elsewhere Hecht quotes Galileo's recognition that a
horizontal 'plane' ultimately has curvature with the
earth.)

There were other proposals for principles of inertia. For example Kepler thought that "each body in proportion to its matter possesses a certain inertial resistance to motion. This inertia provides a state of rest for the body" (when not acted on by a force to maintain the motion). (Bruce Stephenson, in 'Kepler's Physical Astronomy' (1987) showed how Kepler's idea of force was of something that maintains velocity, Kepler did not have the later idea of accelerative force.)

A little later on, Descartes generalized the law of inertia to include linearity and persistence of motion in the absence of force. Hecht points out, though (in the paper cited above), that

> "Although Descartes got it right, it was for the wrong reason; as he
> put it, “[R]est is contrary to motion, and nothing by its own nature
> can tend toward its contrary… .” Not so; rest and uniform motion are
> actually indistinguishable."

So there were indeed others, before Newton as well as after, who accepted the law of inertia.

The questioner here wants to know what experiments Newton made in support of his first law. The historical evidence shows that this part of the question is based on an uninformed mistake. First, Newton nowhere claimed the first law as his own, and second, it was one of the things he called the "principles ... receiv'd by mathematicians, and ... confirm'd by abundance of experiments", i.e. experiments by others.

Comment: Also, Galileo discusses inertial motion on board a ship moving with constant velocity both in *Two New Sciences* and in *Dialogue Concerning the Two Chief World Systems*.

Comment: From my reading of Galileo (in translation) I gathered that he took constant speed as a body's 'default' motion, as for a body travelling on a frictionless track on the Earth's surface, but that he didn't insist on a straight line.

Comment: @Philip Wood : Yes I agree. Included in Hecht's point (which I didn't quote at greater length as this is long enough already), was that Galileo's bodies on horizontal tracks were nevertheless all affected by gravity, so Galileo appears not to have contemplated totally force-free motion.

Answer (score 1):

Galileo Galilei, a predecessor to Newton, already had formulated the law of inertia. Newton essentially just took it, and expanded upon it.

Comment: But did Galileo believe an object in motion remained in motion?

Comment: @releseabe Yes, given he formulated said law.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, from the human perspective of every-day life, very few phenomena take place in isolation so they are easily misunderstood via our intuition. The fact that an object in motion continues that motion when undisturbed is not easily grasped by the intuition because *we in daily life never really see anything moving undisturbed*. There is so often also air drag, frictions, maybe wind blows and the like interferring.

But build a vacuum chamber and do the experiment there, and you will see the effect. Or investigate celestial objects' motion and you will see it there also. For certain phenomena you can be lucky to design an experiment in a way that cancels out some of the unwanted disturbances, such as when letting two objects falling from a high place to show that they land at the same time - intuition would disagree with this claim, but if you drop two equally shaped objects of different masses from a high place and shape them in a way where air drag will be reduced, then the effect is quite clear to see suddenly.

Your actual question: "*was there anyone else who believed this?*" is a question that should be asked on the SE site for the history of science and mathematics since this is a historical matter rather than a physical matter. I hope my answer gives at least some appreciation of the truthfulness of how our laws of physics are described even though we never truly experience them in isolation in usual life.

Comment: Newton I am pretty sure built no vacuum chamber and that would not have helped anyway. Perhaps a long, smooth or lubricated track would have suggested that objects can continue in motion.

Comment: @releseabe Maybe some clues to how Newton found out can be found in his Principia, his original publication from the 1600s. Also I'd think that this is more of a historical question so you might get better answers on the physics history SE site.

Answer (score 0):

It's a definition he made up.

He mostly didn't see things continue in motion forever. He never saw that, since he died before anything could continue in motion forever. But he said that a force was anything that kept things from continuing in a straight line forever.

It just made sense that things would continue doing the same forever unless something else interfered. Something else always interferes, and "force" was the name he gave to the things that made the changes.